# Структуры данных в SQL-запросе

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Мне нужно сделать в таблице MySQL такое поле, которое бы имело заданную структуру, наподобие Си, а-ля

```
 struct{int name, int weight, int length}
```

при этом при попытке положить туда какое-либо другое значение (скалярное, либо не этой структуры) выдавалось бы предупреждение а лучше ошибка о невозможности положить такое значение в таблицу.
Возможно ли как-то сделать это средствами SQL?
Используемая rdbms - mysql.

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю, можно или нет. В гугле не нашел ничего такого. Я бы хранил данные в поле в формате json. На счет другого значения - при записи надо это делать вручную, т.е. не mysql. Из плюсов - можно храть сколько угодно значений в поле. Из минусов - это все надо постоянно парсить.

Comment: Вам бы на PostgreSQL поглядеть с его композитными типами - он такое умеет. Или даже может быть на NoSQL.

Comment: Та он уже какой-то формат JSON советуют. Надо в сторону него посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я знаю на уровне мускула такого контроля формата вводимых данных не сделаешь (если только не перекомпилировать с добавлением своих функций - открытый ведь код, кстати, тоже выход!), лучше контролировать на уровне php. В принципе можно хранить в бинарном виде и читать побайтно пиэчпишкой, но это идеологически неверно для пхп. Имхо, лучше придерживаться принципа атомарности и разбить "структуру" на отдельные столбцы, а если структура содержит структуру, то и на отдельные связанные таблицы (как и задумывались базы данных). Не могу представить себе практическую задачу, где "лучше" хранить данные в такой структуре в одном столбце. В большинстве случаев надо "не быть слишком умным" и придерживаться рельефа местности (то бишь - идеологии rdbms). Ради любопытства - что за задача?

Comment: задача - добавить теги к сообщению. но хочется сделать это красиво, а не через задницу.

Comment: Для тегов, наиболее рациональный вариант - сделать две таблицы. В одной будет список всех тегов, а во второй связи между тегами и сообщениями. Не забывайте о том, что вам по этим тегам придется делать выборки, а для этого нужно строить индексы. Для индексирования полей в БД есть штатные средства, а вот вашу структуру проиндексировать точно никак не получится.

Comment: Ну да, не изобретать новых сущностей без особой необходимости - это и есть красиво и не через задницу, если  только нет каких-то особенностей, кроме указанных (теги с сообщениями), то способ KiTE и есть самый красивый, без выкрутасов и правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Извените, если не так понял, но по-моему это нужно поступить так:

Как и написано в ответе, контролировать формат данных для запроса лучше на уровне php (Тут это и проще и зачем лишний раз дёргать могучий мускул сервер). Поэтому мой вариант - массивы.

Я представляю теги входящими данными, посленные через глобальные массивы обработчику. Поэтому можно разбить входящую строку на подстроки функцией explode() (Предварительно отфильтровав и проверив формат данных), и в базу записать сериализованный массив (serialize()), а на выводе доставать данные из обыкновенной ячейки, распаковывать и выводить (Для распаковки есть обратная функция unserialize()).

Comment: А выводить список постов по заданному тегу как будешь, если у тебя эти самые теги будут лежать массивом в одном из полей поста?
unserialize/serialize - удобные функции, но не в этом случае.

Comment: А как же оператор LIKE чудесного языка SQL ? :)

Нужно будет распаковать массив и передать нужное значение для перелинковки GET методом другому модулю, который расшифрует, пофильтрует и сделает запрос к базе с последующим выводом ответа

Я сам пишу модули под CMS DLE и такой вот метод с реализацией "Перелинковки" уже использовал в одном из последних модулей и с LIKE прекрасно мне в этом помог :)

Comment: >А как же оператор LIKE чудесного языка SQL ? :)
No comments... Вот так и получается говнокод. В этом случае LIKE не использует индексы. С каждым новым постом выборка по тегам будет тяжелеть.

Однажды перепиливал кусок кода с похожей реализацией. Там каждый запрос к таблице с 50k записей висел по 30 сек.

Comment: @rashpil, sales-ы производителей железа рукоплещут Вам.